# Why config static variables are not working in my case?

Tags: php, scope, static, static-methods, codeigniter-4

I am using a custom Config file in Codeigniter 4. I populate its static variables by calling a method `load_values()` & then use those static variables in BaseController. Its working fine in BaseController but when I try to use those same variables in AdminController extended from BaseController its variables are shown empty. I don't call the method `load_values()` in AdminController as its extended from BaseController.
Following are details.

Why config file variables are shown empty in  AdminController?
I tried to debug & watch variables values but could not trace the root cause.

**BaseController:**

```
$this->config = config('My_config');
// Following load_values() method loads users names & populates 
//other static variables (eg: $users_array) of config class 'My_config'. 
//I dont call this method again in AdminController
$this->config::load_values();  
echo $this->config::$users_array[0];  // Prints User Name
```

**AdminController extends BaseController:**

```
$this->config = config('My_config');
echo $this->config::$users_array[0]; // Empty
```

`$this->config::$users_array[0];` prints values in BaseController but don't print anything in AdminController. Please advise.

Comment: Where is the `load_values()` method coming from? `$this->config = config('My_config');` is all that's required to store a configuration file into a variable in CI4 https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html

Comment: `load_values()` is a static method and populates static variables of the config file from json files.